# centos - cannot create two symlinks to /var/www/html

Tags: centos, symbolic-link, centos-7

I have two users chrooted to their home directories, that need access to /var/www/html. I tried to solve this by creating a files directory within their directories and in that files directory create a html directory. Now when i did `sudo mount --bind /home/ibrahim/files/html /var/www/html` it worked fine... When i tried `sudo mount --bind /home/faisal/files/html /var/www/html` his directory was still empty, and didn't contain the files in /var/www/html.

I also added this to fstab:

```
/home/ibrahim/files/html /var/www/html          none    bind    0 0
/home/faisal/files/html /var/www/html          none    bind    0 0
```

**Please answer this quickly.**

Comment: Please answer this quickly.

Comment: That’s *not* a symlink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need to swap arguments, since source directory goes first
`sudo mount --bind /var/www/html /home/ibrahim/files/html`
`sudo mount --bind /var/www/html /home/faisal/files/html`
and in `/etc/fstab` as well

```
/var/www/html /home/ibrahim/files/html           none    bind    0 0
/var/www/html /home/faisal/files/html            none    bind    0 0
```

Comment: Whoops, my bad..